# How can I show/hide a div with a background image without it fading in?

Tags: jquery, hide, show

Currently I have images that, on mouseover, shows an img over another, but it fades in. I simply want it to show with no fade.

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fade').hover(function() { 
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
    },function() { 
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0}); 
    })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try `$(this).find('.caption').show()` instead of `$('.caption', this).show();`

Comment: As you can see above, I've basically gotten the result I'm looking for, but need a bit of a different reaction from the mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

Set animation duration to 0 like this:

```
$(this).stop().animate({ "opacity" : 1 }, 0);
```